# Memory Leak caused by Initializer List?

Tags: c++, oop, memory-leaks, valgrind, initializer

I'm having memory leaks in my code, according to valgrind all of them come from the constructor in my class; here its  code:

```
  School::School(unsigned int NumberOfClasses[]) :
        first(*new Grade<Student, std::equal_to<Student>>(NumberOfClasses[0])),
        second(*new Grade<Student, std::equal_to<Student>>(NumberOfClasses[1])),
        third(*new Grade<Student, std::equal_to<Student>>(NumberOfClasses[2])) {

}
```

Grade is a special array template I created that gets both an element (in this case, a Student) and a compare function for the element (which I also provided); it has both a Constructor and a Destructor that works without memory leaks. Here is the signature of the constructor:

```
Grade<Element, Compare> :: Grade(unsigned int size);
```

Since my school is 3 Grades, its destructor is `=default;`

This is what I get from valgrind:

```
    8 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 1 of 6
==21426==    at 0x4C2A888: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:423)
==21426==    by 0x4041B8: Grade<BmbSchool::Student, std::equal_to<BmbSchool::Student> >::Grade(unsigned int) (GradeImp.h:9)
==21426==    by 0x40298B: BmbSchool::School::Grade(unsigned int*) (School.cpp:27)
==21426==    by 0x405B6C: main (BmbSchool.cpp:148)
```

Another kind of error I get, quite similiar, is:

```
==21426== 32 (24 direct, 8 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 6
==21426==    at 0x4C2A1E3: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==21426==    by 0x402974: BmbSchool::School::Grade(unsigned int*) (School.cpp:28)
==21426==    by 0x405B6C: main (BmbSchool.cpp:148)
```

Any way it makes sense? How can I solve this? I can assume that there won't be any bad_alloc exceptions thrown when defining the arrays.

edit: The definition to school is -

```
    Grade<Student, std::equal_to<Student>> first;
    Grade<Student, std::equal_to<Student>> second;
    Grade<Student, std::equal_to<Student>> third;
```

Comment: Can you please provide definition of your `School` class?

Comment: Pretty much never do `*new ...`.  Just remove the `*new` and life will be better.

Comment: Its hard to not leak after a `*new`. It makes the pointer returned by `new` inaccessible. Depending on what you do with the result of `*` you *may* be able to get it back. But it's pretty much always a mistake. You may be influenced by other langues like Java or C# where `new` is required to instantiate anything. In C++, this is not the case. It favors value semantics and even when dynamic allocation is required `new` is discouraged in favor of `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared`.

Comment: Besides the above... If `first`, etc..  are reference members, they likely should not be. And since there is no [mcve]...

Answer (score 1):

The leak is in your misuse of `new`.  You are dynamically allocating 3 `Grade` objects, but are then dereferencing the pointers to pass those objects to the copy constructor of your 3 data members. You never `delete` the objects you `new`'ed, hence the leaking.

You don't need to use `new` at all in this situation.  Simply pass your input values directly to the same constructor of the data members themselves that you were calling with `new`:

```cpp
School::School(unsigned int NumberOfClasses[]) :
    first(NumberOfClasses[0]),
    second(NumberOfClasses[1]),
    third(NumberOfClasses[2])
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++11 or later, you can use std::array, so something like

```
 School::School(const std::array<unsigned int, 3>& NumberOfClasses) :
 // as Remy Lebeau's answer
```

I would expect compilers to produce similar if not the same machine code, but you will gain some compile-time checking.